# How would an originalist interpret a change in the implementation of a broad language?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, interpretation

The following question is inspired by a point made by Justice Breyer in the [following link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmv5Tz7w5pk), but Justice Scalia did not specifically address this point, so I wondered how an originalist would address it.

The following example will follow USA law-approving process, but the answer may be applied to every nation.

The following questions should be answered using an "originalist" mode of law interpretation.

Suppose the 1st of January 2000 the following law is enacted by Congress and signed by the President:

> No one can kill an animal belonging to an endangered species.
>
> Whoever kills an animal belonging to an endangered species will be
> punished with 20 years in jail.

The 2nd of January 2000 a national poll is conducted. The poll has a 100% coverage (every american is interviewed and every american responds). The poll asks the intervieweds "is a red squirrel an endangered species?". Everybody responds "no". I hope that, by this expedient, I have fixed the *original* public meaning of the statute.

The 2nd of January 2020 (20 years later), another poll is conducted. Same question, 100% coverage, everybody now responds "yes". The public meaning has changed (right?).

In fact, there are now very few red squirrels: in the past 20 years, the meat of the red squirrel was found to be very tasty, or the fur very fashion, and so on. In particular, there are 2 red squirrels in all the USA, one male and one female, so we are still in time to save the species.

1. The 3rd of January 2020 I kill one of the two red squirrels remaining. Will I go to jail for 20 years?

If the answer to (1) is "no", I am satisfied. Thank you.

If the answer to (1) is "yes" (I will go to jail), I have a follow-up question.

2. a. Suppose, for the sake of the argument, that on the 15th of December 1791 (the day the Eighth Amendment to the United States Constitution was adopted), nobody thought the death penalty was cruel and unusual. This is what [Justice Scalia thinks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvttIukZEtM) (at 14:27).

b. In the law enacted the 2nd of January 2000 (the one about the endangered species), the punishment for killing an endangered species is death.

c. In the 2nd of January 2020 poll (20 years later), after the question "Is a red squirrel an endangered species?" (which everybody answer with a "yes"), there is the question "is the death penalty cruel and unusual?" to which everybody responds "yes".

d. The 3rd of January 2020 I kill a red squirrel. Will I be subject to the death penalty?

With an originalist perspective, you should answer 2d with a "yes". It doesn't matter that the public meaning has changed, you need a formal amendment to the Constitution. Then, why you answered "yes" to question 1? Why it did matter in question 1 that the public meaning has changed?

Sorry if I make confusion.

Comment: The question is... Convoluted. Try a better example? Because "endangered species" is a word of art *already defined in law* by the [Washington Convention Appendices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CITES)

Comment: I'm not sure this example is well chosen, because in reality, statute does and did prescribe a very specific way to determine if a species is endangered: [16 USC 1533](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/16/1533).  Surely a court, under any perspective, would follow that definition and not public opinion.

Comment: @Trish: Yes, I believe so; I wrote my comment simultaneously to yours.  Though I think the Endangered Species Act contains provisions that go beyond the terms of the Convention.

Comment: @NateEldredge and the 1533 is *additionally* to [16 USC 1531 a4F](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/16/1531), which pointed to [CITES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CITES) as an automatic determination when a thing is endangered and has to be protected. CITES Appendices regularity get updated, and would pick up the squirrel lack at *latest* in 2018, putting it on the index and thus banning it long before the hypothetical.

Comment: This question seems more like an essay- OP clearly has an answer in mind that they intend to prove.

Comment: You have to be more precise than asking about "originalism", because there are many kinds of originalism. What you are describing sound most like what is sometimes known as "semantic originalism". Are you asking how Dworkin or Solum would rule in this case?

Comment: The problem with your reasoning is that a species can _become_ endangered.  The meaning of "endangered species" doesn't need to change in order for the set of species included to change (due to population/environmental changes).

Comment: @Trish suppose for the sake of the argument that "endangered species" is not defined in any other statute, and my hypothetical statute is everything the court has. Or, instead, suppose that the law I hypothesized is a Constitutional Amendment, which trumps the other statute (i'm still not sure about that though, maybe I will open another question on that)

Comment: @Nate Eldredge suppose for the sake of the argument that "endangered species" is not defined in any other statute, and my hypothetical statute is everything the court has. Or, instead, suppose that the law I hypothesized is a Constitutional Amendment, which trumps the other statute (i'm still not sure about that though, maybe I will open another question on that)

Comment: @Studoku no, I would like to knoe how an originalist would rule on this question, and how he/she would reply to Justice Breyer remark. also `OP clearly has an answer in mind that they intend to prove` is far-fetched and assuming

Comment: @user6726 unfortunately I am not familiar with the different flavors of originalism. I would like to know how Justice Scalia or Justice Thomas would rule on that question. If that does not satisfy you, please give me some time to get familiar with the different flavors. Do you have some link where I can learn the different flavors?

Comment: @RyanM well also a punishment can *become* unusual. For example, hanging was usual in the past and unusual now. Thus now it would satisfy the requirement of "cruel and unusual"

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @raffaem I believe, because it is very clear that the example doesn't work at all, because we could point to actual law, how it is written, and that back in the 1970s congress chose to adopt among others CITES that contains a regularly updated list of species compiled by an international team of experts, then add to that who can add more species to be endangered. If the 16 USC chapter wouldn't exist at all, the law would have been challenged on January 3rd 2020 as lacking the definition parts.

Comment: If there is no definition then the law is very likely [void for vagueness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagueness_doctrine).

Comment: @NateEldredge why the "cruel and unusual punishment" clause of the Eight Amendment is not void for vagueness?

Comment: @raffaem, read this pape, Semantic originalism by L. Solum.: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1120244

Comment: @raffaem: The vagueness doctrine is a test for constitutionality - a statute which is too vague is held to be unconstitutional as it violates due process.  But the Eighth Amendment is not a statue; it *is* the Constitution. So it can't be unconstitutional no matter how vague it is.

Comment: @user6726 Thank you very much, I will read it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

### What is an "endangered species"?

Normally, this would be defined in the law. In fact, the *actual* [Endangered Species Act](https://www.fws.gov/endangered/laws-policies/section-4.html) does exactly that:

> DEFINITIONS
>
> SEC. 4. (a) GENERAL.
>
> (1) The Secretary shall by regulation promulgated in accordance with subsection (b) determine whether any species is an endangered species or a threatened species because of ...

So, it's very clear for the purposes of this Act what an "endangered species" is. Red squirrels are an endangered species and you are going to jail if at the time you killed one the secretary of the Environment Department had determined they were and had promulgated that decision as required by the act.

### However, that just begs the question ...

Let's assume the Act did not define "endangered species". It doesn't have to. So what happens?

When you go to trial, the judge will determine what "endangered species" means and whether red squirrels fit within the definition.

If you are not the first person tried under the act, then there will be a precedent that the judge will either be required to follow (if it's from a court higher in the hierarchy) or is likely to follow (if it's at the same level or lower in the hierarchy or in a parallel hierarchy).

If you are the first person, then they will probably start with a dictionary. Merriam Webster is a solid US based dictionary and it [says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endangered%20species):

> a species threatened with extinction

The lawyers for both sides will introduce evidence as to what that means and if it does or doesn't include red squirrels. The polls will be inadmissible because opinions aren't allowed as evidence unless they come from an expert. So your trial is likely to see a bunch of zoologists, ecologists, climatologists, etc. giving their opinion on what endangered species are and if red squirrels are one.

It is possible that on a case decided at a given time, red squirrels are no endangered under the accepted definition and that another time, they are endangered. Whether a jurist in an originalist or not won't change that.

Comment: The Congress finds and declares that—he United States has pledged itself as a sovereign state in the international community to conserve to the extent practicable the various species of fish or wildlife and plants facing extinction, pursuant to—the Convention on International Trade in Endangered Species of Wild Fauna and Flora; [among other treaties] 16 U.S. Code § 1531 - Congressional findings and declaration of purposes and policy - makes CITES another source for a list of species that automagically have to be made endangered.